# CRM Online. Logging in causes crash

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

Dynamics CRM Online suddenly crashed and whenever  I try to log back into my organization (on various browsers) I keep getting this "Site Map Error".
[image]

When searching for the problem I see various other people who have come across the same problem. A general suggestion has been to reset the sitemap using the Xrm toolbox. This has only worked for a few it appears.

I cannot even get to reset anything since this is the only window in my organization I can access.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do not put answers to your question within the question. Move it to the Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem.

1. Go to https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/, downloading the toolbox.
2. Connect your organization to the toolbox
3. Open the sitemap editor
4. choose more actions (dropdown) -> Select "Reset Dynamics 365 (8.2) Sitemap to default".
5. Say yes to the prompt that says your organization is not a Dynamics 365. 6. Open organization, log in and int works.

Regards to this link https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/195922